# The easiest way to serve a page to localhost on OS X

Tags: macos, webserver, localhost

I have a page that I need to serve on localhost for the fonts to appear properly.

What is the easiest way to do this (on a Mac)?

Comment: I don't see the connection with *programming*... your question seems more the question of a *user* of an OS and, as such, is probably more suited to SuperUser than StackOverflow.

Comment: _Programming_ is a pretty high standard; seems like there is a lot of around coding on this site and this question/answer seemed relevant to what I needed in the process of coding a page.  I was trying to find a help page that discusses what is on/off topic for StackOverflow; if you have one please leave in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open `terminal`.
2. Navigate to the folder (directory) containing the file you want to serve.
3. `php -S localhost:8080`
4. Go to `http://localhost:8080` in the browser.